# How did Amy get pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, gone-girl

At the end of *Gone Girl*, Amy is pregnant and this is the reason that Nick decides to stay with her.

However, it is unclear to me who the father really is.

Is it Desi or is it Nick from before the disappearance?

Is this clarified in the book?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes? I do not see what is so wrong with my question.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes either. Was wondering the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_Girl_(film)) clarifies:

> Nick intends to leave Amy and expose her lies, but Amy reveals she is pregnant, having **artificially inseminated herself with Nick's sperm** stored at a fertility clinic.

...the same is true in the [**novel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_Girl_(novel)):

> Amy uses Nick's semen they had saved at a fertility clinic to make herself pregnant.